# How to find weekday name from the Python's Datetime object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary, keyerror

So I just started learning python and tried to make a program that tells you day on a given day. I discovered `datetime` and tried to use it, but the problem is I am getting key error even though the key is present.

Here's my code:

```
import datetime

def day_finder(dd,mm,yy):

    tags = { '1' : 'Monday' ,'2' : 'Tuesday' ,'3' : 'Wednesday' ,'4' : 'Thursday' ,'5' : 'Friday' ,'6' : 'Saturday' ,'7' : 'Sunday' }
    return tags[int(datetime.datetime(yy,mm,dd).isoweekday())]


d = int(input("Enter a date"))
m = int(input("Enter a month"))
y = int(input("Enter a year"))

print (day_finder(d,m,y))
```

Comment: You are converting week of day to int where the keys of the dictionary is clearly string. That is why the error

Comment: Easiest way is to just use input() instead of int(input())

Comment: if i use input() it will give TypeError

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are searching for an `int` weekday number, but instead you should be checking for the string because the keys in your *dictionary* are of `str` type. For example:

```
>>> tags = { '1' : 'Monday' ,'2' : 'Tuesday' ,'3' : 'Wednesday' ,'4' : 'Thursday' ,'5' : 'Friday' ,'6' : 'Saturday' ,'7' : 'Sunday' }

>>> import datetime
>>> tags[str(datetime.datetime(1990,03,28).isoweekday())]
'Wednesday'
```

However, you do not need a `dict` object to get the weekday name based on the key day number. You may get the desired result via using `.strftime('%A')` on the `datetime` object as:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1990,03,28).strftime("%A")
'Wednesday'
```

Answer (score 1):

`isoweekday` returns an integer. The keys of your dictionary are strings.

You don't need to call `int` on the result as it is already an int - either replace that with `str`, or use integers as the keys of your dict.

Comment: if i remove the '' in dict it will turn them in integers?

Answer (score 0):

`keys` in your `tags` object are `str` values, however you convert them to `int`(which they already are) and then try to access value by `int` value, that's why you get `KeyError`.

Fix would be convert them to `str` and everything would work.

```
return tags[str(datetime.datetime(yy,mm,dd).isoweekday())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try string on lookup not integer.

```
return tags[str(datetime.datetime(yy,mm,dd).isoweekday())]
```